# MediaElementjs on iphone(safari) - TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, mediaelement.js, mediaelement

I'm using the [MediaElementjs player](http://mediaelementjs.com/), but somehow when I add a playlist function it doesn't work on Safari anymore (tested on iphone and pc with windows 7). It works fine on all the other browsers. 
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I uploaded the project with a few mp3 files to DropBox. [You can download it here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7wua9o6dv6lnqwp/player.rar)

Edit (3/9/14):
I turned on the debug mode on the iphone and got the following error message:

> Javascript: Error
>
> undefined
>
> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I solved it myself :D

The main problem was that I called mejsloader.js before the establishment of the audio tag in the html.